# Akita query this.selectAll returning empty list before service call completes

Tags: angular, typescript, state-management, angular-akita, akita

This is my widgetquery.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class WidgetQuery extends QueryEntity<WidgetState, WidgetTO> {
  public Widget$: Observable<WidgetTO> = this.selectActive().filter(k => !!k);
  public WidgetHistorikk$: Observable<WidgetTO[]> = this.selectAll({sortBy: 'WidgetId', sortByOrder: Order.DESC}).filter(k => !!k);

  constructor(protected store: WidgetStore) {
    super(store);
  }
}
```

In the front end I am using *ngIf like so:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="widgetHistorikk$ | async"> ... </ng-container>
```

The constructor in my component calls this function, to get widgets from a service call (the service call is successful...)

```
  private fetchWidgetHistorikk() {
    this.WidgetService.getWidgetHistorikk().filter(h => !!h).subscribe(liste => {
      this.WidgetStore.add(liste);
    });
  }
```

However the selectAll query is returning an empty list `[ ]` before it returns the real data `[ widget1, widget2 ]`.

So I am getting an empty list, and then the real data (a populated list).

I dont want the empty list that comes first (even though it is possible the real data can be an empty list sometimes)...

Why am I getting the first empty list from akita?

Can I use some sort of "flag" or "initialisation state" to tell akita: don't return data from the query until my service call completes, and data is added to the store via this line `this.WidgetStore.add(liste);` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity store, you can simply set loading to true in the initial state and after you got the response you can change it to false, and in your query check if the state is loading show some loading UI or do whatever you want.

```
store.setLoading(true);
```

and also you can use `combineLatest` or to get data when loading is done.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the empty list because Akita always emits the initial value, as said in the [docs](https://datorama.github.io/akita/docs/query). You can skip that with rxjs `skip(1)` (or filter out empty/undef. values)

If you just don't want to show empty content on the UI, you can just say

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(widgetHistorikk$ | async)?.length > 0"> ... </ng-container>
```

Third option would be to hide the content when Store's *loading status* is true

Comment: thanks. how do i filter the loading status in an *ngIF="..." ?

Comment: @vikingsteve well you could store it in a variable (`loading$: Observable<boolean>`) and then use it in your template just like any other variable